# How to Measure the SLA Performance of IT Techs in Managed Services Provider?

Tags: performance, kpi

My company provides IT managed services support to multiple clients that have SLA agreements with us. We have multiple technicians tackling the many tickets that flow in.

For each ticket we have two SLA levels:

- Responded (Whether we responded to ticket within a time frame.)
- Resolved (Whether ticket was resolved within a time frame.)

We use a software system (ConnectWise) that tracks the time resolved, time responded, and the technician(s) that completed those stages of the ticket. Sometimes just one tech may complete all cycles of a ticket's SLA but sometimes a team of people may be part of a ticket (e.g. one person responded, then he passed it on another tech and a couple other techs may work on it too).

**What is the most accurate way to gauge each tech's SLA performance on these tickets?**

One caveat that impedes an accurate SLA performance by technician is that ConnectWise only associates ONE person that responded and ONE person that resolved the ticket.  Here are some scenarios.

- We may have a tech who just started his shift and saw a ticket that hasn't been responded for some time. He responds to it, ConnectWise labeled him as the responder, but then he may be hit with a missed response-SLA.
- A ticket may pass through different hands and the last person who worked on it and resolved it tagged the ticket Resolved. But he may get hit with a missed Resolved-SLA and this isn't fair because he may not be the one working on resolving it from beginning to end.

I'd appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: Your metrics do not distinguish between ticket 1 "What is the key next to the W on the keyboard?"  and ticket 2 "Please write me a new operating system  that exceeds the A1 trust level in the Orange book, and runs on all hardware."  This is perplexing. I think you're motivating your technicians to cherry pick the tickets, which is not going to result in client satisfaction. Or (more likely), I don't understand the scenario.

Comment: This appears to be a question about operations/ITIL, not about projects.

Comment: While questions about metrics can be on topic, this question is about ongoing support operations rather than project management.

Answer (score 1):

Am I late for the party?

Well, there are many ways to arrive at the metrics and it depends on how you would want to prepare yourself for the future. For example, an in-depth analysis requires every data point to be captured - for example, if you consider the chain from the ticket assigned to your team to ticket closure by your Client, you will have various links to unearth. But, if you keep tracking all those links, you will end-up only tracking without arriving at an action item(s) that could possibly create value-add to your esteemed Client and to your Organization.

**What to do?**

First and foremost, glance through your contract to understand what your SLA's are?, As of date, are you working on all those SLA's mentioned in the Contract?, How you do you flare?, What are the outliers?, What are the action-items you have in your plate to work upon?, Does your Client need more information about your tickets other than whatever has been mentioned in the Contract? If you are good until here, then it means, you are good go with your Client as well.

**What next?**

The next activity shall be to see how you would want to create value-add to your organization. Ask questions internally to understand how would you want to manage your resources? - Is it hourly? or by total tickets addressed per day? or tickets with billing hours/rate ratio?

All these variables would determine on how you would want to drive your employees and your project internally.

You will always need to reverse engineer to arrive at the metrics by answering various questions that would lead to you to the next level.

Hope this helps.